# Contact us form with Angularjs

Tags: php, html, angularjs

i edited the post to have more details so thank you for pointing that out :)

I want to create a contact form so that users can send emails directly from the website to my email address. The problem iam having is that it doesn't work no matter what script or guide i used.

Now i cleaned my code so that it is easier to see if something is wrong so i don't have anything to validate the input text.

what i currently have are  3 files in my server which are contact.php, contact.html and app.js and i created an email account on the same server because it is part of the package when i hosted it.

My controller and html code:

```js
app.controller("contactController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {


        $scope.formData = {

            subject: '',
            email: '',
            message: ''
        };
        console.log(formData);
        // process the form
        $scope.processForm = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'contact.php',
                data: $scope.formData,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            })


        };


    } ]);
```

```html
<div class=" container formcontainer">
        
      <form method="post">
            
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject..." ng-model="formData.subject">
            
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email..." ng-model="formData.email">
         
            <textarea  rows="5" cols="50" class="form-control" placeholder="You message" ng-model="formData.message"></textarea>
           
            <button type="submit" ng-click="processForm()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Submit!</button>
      </form>
   </div>
```

And my php

```
<?php


$post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($post_data);



//email information
$to = "lurtze@hotmail.com";

$subject = $data['subject'];
$userEmail=$data['email'];
$message=$data['message'];



$headers = 'From: ' . $userEmail . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To:'.$userEmail . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

//php mail function to send email on your email address
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

//Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }

?>
```

Now i have been getting the error when i console log my code, 
ReferenceError: formData is not defined

What i tried to do is send an array to the php script and then send the information as a email.

As i mentioned before i have tried multiple guides and code snippets but couldn't get it to work So i appreciate any help i can get!

Comment: Send the data in an AJAX request to a server-side PHP script, which will send the email.

Comment: Some code would be nice. But you should probably have your Angular controller pass the necessary data in an ajax call to a serverside php script that actually sends the email. Mail aliases and/or hotmail has no relevance in this particular issue (you should be able to send to any mail address from your script).

Comment: I would appreciate it if you take a second look on my post and see what i have done wrongly :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not send the mail via your AngularJS Application!
Send your request to your server, which will send the main for the request

Comment: Hi i just edited the post so you can see more details, sorry that i didn't do that from the start :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup an outgoing email server or use an API from a service provider.
2. Setup an API calling of which can send emails via what was setup in step 1.
3. Send requests from the contact form to the API you setup in step 2.